# Python login script with cookie save

Tags: python, cookies, autologin

I'm not an expert at Python neither a developer but I'm trying to make a Python script that automatically connect to Adidas website using my credentials and save the cookie for future uses.

I've manage to connect by launching the browser but I don't know how to do this silently (without showing the browser page).

```
import mechanize
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
import cookielib
import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
import re
import sys
import StringIO
from urllib2 import HTTPError
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pickle

##########################################################

adidasLoginPage = "https://www.adidas.com/us/myaccount-create-or-login"
sleepSeconds = 2
emailUsername = "TOTO@toto.com"
emailPassword = "mypassword"
global threeDigit

##########################################################

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def login():

    drivers.get(adidasLoginPage)
    time.sleep(sleepSeconds)

    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("loginaccountframe"))
    emailBox = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    emailBox.send_keys(emailUsername)

    passwordBox = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    passwordBox.send_keys(emailPassword)
    time.sleep(sleepSeconds)

    loginButton = driver.find_element_by_id("signinSubmit")
    loginButton.click()

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl","wb"))

login()
###############################################################
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

You are using `Chrome` webdriver so selenium opens Chrome to load the page. You can use a headless browser like `PhantomJS` to do this without opening any browsers. I think that's what you want.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

You of course need to install PhantomJS for this.

On OS X, I install PhantomJS using Homebrew:

```
brew install phantomjs
```

Please consult the PhantomJS docs for installation on your operating system.